# How to retrieve saved id then pass as selected test in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a modal form where user enters details like for an item,the modal has a select option where user can select the item category there are savings,i have no problem here.the issue is when the user want to edit some details of the item.u will require to retrieve the item.here is my issue i cant get the category saved transferred back to the select option then set is as selected.
how can i do this.//id of selected category is the one that is inserted to db.

```
$.get(
  '../Inventory/PopulateCategory',
  {},
  function (data) {
    $('#Category').empty();

    $.each(data,
        function (key, value) {
            $('#Category')
              .append($("<option />")
              .val(value.StockCategoryId)
              .html(value.StockCategory));
        });
  },
  'json'
);
```

this is how i retrieve the value,am able to load input but cant get to load the correct saved item to select.

```
function EditCompanyRecord(_id) {
  var url = "/Inventory/itemEdit?_id=" + _id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var currcat = obj.StockCategory;
        var _vat = obj.taxcode;
        $("#StockId").val(_id);
        $("#Description").val(obj.description);
        $('#Category').val(obj.StockCategory)
      //i need to reverse and get save id as the selected category
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear(Complex sentence formation). Can you reframe the sentence with your apps actual scenario you are trying to implement using simple sentence.

Comment: Don't add value to the #Category. Category is a select. You want to populate each <option>  with all the different StockCategory (s).

Answer (score 0):

The value persisted as category for the stock is the category name/title.
While the options input uses the category id for the value.

In order to have persisted category for the stock selected in the category options, you need to **find the id for the persisted category** for the stock in the category options. *e.g.*

```
const $objStockCategoryId = $('#Category').children().filter((i, e) => 
  e.text === obj.StockCategory);
```

Then select the category option

```
$('#Category').val($objStockCategoryId.val());
```

However, I suggest to set a data attribute in the category options for a succinct DOM query. e.g.

```
$.each(data,
    function (key, value) {
      $('#Category')
        .append(
          $("<option />")
            .attr('data-name', value.StockCategory)
            .val(value.StockCategoryId)
            .html(value.StockCategory)
       );
    });

const $objStockCategoryId = $('#Category')
                              .find(`[data-name="${obj.StockCategory}"]`);

$('#Category').val($objStockCategoryId.val());
```